# Session closed when inside ExecutorService

Tags: java, session, jdbc

When I try to call `session.createSQLQuery()` inside `myExecutor.execute(new Runnable() ...)`, I get an exception:

```
SessionException: Session is closed!
```

**Why is the Session closed during `ExecutorService.execute`?**

Do I have to create a new `entityManager` inside the `execute`?

```
ExecutorService executor = newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM function()");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, each thread has its own session. The ExecutorService has its own threads and therefore you would need to manage an entity manager, session and transaction within the executor's thread in your `run()` method.

Comment: In Executor block, how i get the EntityManager object ? @Autowired is not working inside the executor block.